# How to send sms to multiple people in android

Tags: android, sms

I am building a app of sending sms to multiple people at a time . But whenever i tried to send sms ,it close immediately after clicking on send button and app stop working and do not send the messages.How to make it run after closing it.

```
package com.example.sms3;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    ArrayList<String> name1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> phno1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> phno0 = new ArrayList<String>();
    MyAdapter ma;
    Button send;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.get);
        getAllCallLogs(this.getContentResolver());
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        ma = new MyAdapter();
        lv.setAdapter(ma);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                StringBuilder checkedcontacts = new StringBuilder();
                System.out.println(".............." + ma.mCheckStates.size());
                for (int i = 0; i < name1.size(); i++)

                {
                    if (ma.mCheckStates.get(i) == true) {
                        phno0.add(phno1.get(i).toString());
                        checkedcontacts.append(name1.get(i).toString());
                        checkedcontacts.append("\n");

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("..Not Checked......"
                                + name1.get(i).toString());
                    }

                }
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, checkedcontacts, 1000).show();
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                returnIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("name", phno0);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ma.toggle(arg2);
    }

    public void getAllCallLogs(ContentResolver cr) {

        Cursor phones = cr.query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            String name = phones
                    .getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones
                    .getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            System.out.println(".................." + phoneNumber);
            name1.add(name);
            phno1.add(phoneNumber);
        }

        phones.close();
    }

    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements
            CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
        private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
        LayoutInflater mInflater;
        TextView tv1, tv;
        CheckBox cb;

        MyAdapter() {
            mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(name1.size());
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return name1.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View vi = convertView;
            if (convertView == null)
                vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv1 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            tv.setText("Name :" + name1.get(position));
            tv1.setText("Phone No :" + phno1.get(position));
            cb.setTag(position);
            cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
            cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

            return vi;
        }

        public boolean isChecked(int position) {
            return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
        }

        public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
            mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
        }

        public void toggle(int position) {
            setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);
        }

    }
}
```

SmsMultiple.java

```
package com.example.sms3;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SmsMultiple extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    BroadcastReceiver smsSentReciver, smsSentDelivery;
    EditText ed1, ed2;
    static int ResultCode = 12;
    ArrayList<String> sendlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    Button b1, b2;
    String contacts = "";
    String delim = ";";
    TextView ed;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.smssend);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        ed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        ed1.setText(null);
        ed2.setText(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(smsSentReciver);
        unregisterReceiver(smsSentDelivery);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        smsSentReciver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "sms has been sent",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic Fail",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Service",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio Off",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

                }
            }

        };
        smsSentDelivery = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sms Delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sms not Delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }
            }

        };
        registerReceiver(smsSentReciver, new IntentFilter("SMS_SENT"));
        registerReceiver(smsSentDelivery, new IntentFilter("SMS_DELIVERED"));

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.button2:
            Intent a = new Intent(SmsMultiple.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(a, ResultCode);
            break;
        case R.id.button1:

            Log.i("SMS", "Sendlist Size: " + sendlist.size());

            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

            String msg = ed2.getText().toString();
            PendingIntent piSend = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                    new Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0);
            PendingIntent piDelivered = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                    new Intent("SMS_DELIVERED"), 0);

            Log.i("SMS", "contacts: " + contacts);

            String[] cellArray;
            ed1.append("");
            contacts = ed1.getText().toString();
            cellArray = contacts.toString().split(";");
ed.setText(contacts);
            for (int a1 = 0; a1 < cellArray.length; a1++) {
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(cellArray[a1].toString(), null, msg,
                        piSend, piDelivered);
            }
            ed1.setText(null);
            ed2.setText(null);

            break;
        }

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
String str= ed1.getText().toString();

        if (requestCode == ResultCode) {

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                sendlist = data.getStringArrayListExtra("name");
                if (sendlist != null) {
                    ed1.setText(null);
                    for (int i = 0; i < sendlist.size(); i++) {
                            ed1.append("<" + sendlist.get(i).toString()+ ">");
                            ed1.append(delim);
                        }

                        ed1.append(str);

                    }

                }

                if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: try to send messages in Background thread (use AsyncTask) it will work event app gets closed.

Comment: can u suggest me..how to do that,just an starting .plzzz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform the background operations you can use either Service class or AsyncTask class.

But your main problem is as below,

You are sending SMS in following for loop,

```
for (int a1 = 0; a1 < cellArray.length; a1++) 
{
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(cellArray[a1].toString(), null, msg,
    piSend, piDelivered);
}
```

While programmatically you have code properly way, But When you are sending an SMS, it take around 300-500 milliseconds to send a single SMS.

Here your for loop will run instantly and it creates problem. So I suggest you to put a delay of atleast 500 ms in loop. This will give a pause time to your application before sending next SMS. You application will be reading to send next SMS.